# In AngularJS, what if you are routing to the same page (same URL and hash)?

Tags: angularjs

In an AngularJS Single Page Application, if you are in the main page and now you route to the second page, and use the "service" (as a global), and use `myService.cityName` to pull data using AJAX (by using `$resource`), that's fine.

But what if on your page header, you also have an input text box, and you can type in a city name, and when the user press Enter, you are routing to the same page (the second page).  So I think browser didn't do anything because it is the exact same URL.  How would you solve this issue or what is the AngularJS's way of handling this?

(**Update:** it is not to refresh or reload a page... it is about, say, you get weather data for a city, and you are on the forecast subpage, with a path of `#/forecast`.  Now at the top search box on the page, you enter a different city and click "Submit" to go to the same path `#/forecast` then nothing will happen)

**Update2**: essentially, in my controller code:

```
$scope.submit = function() {
    $location.path("/dataPage");
}
```

and my form is `<form ng-submit="submit()">`.

so if I am already on the dataPage, then now browser wants to go to dataPage to show new data, but since the path and hash is exactly the same, the browser just will not do anything. (I suppose due to no `hashchange` event happened, so nobody will notify AngularJS to do anything)

Comment: please add some code

Comment: is  it fires your submit event in controller?

Comment: try to use event.preventDefault()

Comment: some code would be useful

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear, if you want a page refresh like *F5*, one solution is at "*Solution for refresh page*". But if you just want to reload things, you could follow "*Solution for reload page*".

**Solution for refresh page:**

To update a page, all that you need to update the model data of controller and the page will be updated accordingly. Ideally, you should never refresh an entire page in *AngualrJS* . If you need to do so, you are not using *AngularJS* correctly .

The `$location` service does not provide access to refreshing the entire page. If you need to refresh the entire page, you need to use the $window.location object.

```
$window.location.href = "YOURPAGEPATH";
```

**Solution for reload page:**

just want to reload things under `ng-view`, re-initialized the current route controller, you could do like below.

```
$route.reload("YOURPATH");
```

> `$route.reload()` will reinitialise the controllers but not the
>   services.

If you want to reset the whole state of your application you can use:

```
$window.location.reload();
```

This is a standard [DOM method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/location/reload) which you can access injecting the [$window service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window)

Also see: `$route` [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route)

**According to `$route` documentation**:

> Causes `$route` service to reload the current route even if $location
>   hasn't changed.   As a result of that, `ngView` creates new scope,
>   `reinstantiates` the controller.

Comment: it is not to refresh or reload a page... I added what it is about to the end of the question

Answer (score 0):

Well you can just save data from request on your global service. And in controller you can bind that data, so if you press submit from header that function should just refresh your data in service.